# ios7 images inUISegmentedControl not scaling

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol, ios7

I need to display an image in a segmented controller on iOs 7. The problem is that the image doesn't scale to fill the segment (it just sits in the middle).

Here is the code:

```
self.segmentedController.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIImage *imageSegmentedLOff;
UIImage *imageSegmentedMOn;

if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {
    imageSegmentedLOff = [[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_SEGMENTED_L_OFF] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0)];
    imageSegmentedLOff = [imageSegmentedLOff imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    imageSegmentedMOn = [[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_SEGMENTED_M_ON] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0)];
    imageSegmentedMOn = [imageSegmentedMOn imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  } else {
    imageSegmentedLOff = [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_SEGMENTED_L_OFF];
    imageSegmentedMOn = [UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_SEGMENTED_M_ON];
}

[self.segmentedController setImage:imageSegmentedLOff forSegmentAtIndex:0];
[self.segmentedController setImage:imageSegmentedMOn forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you setting the images twice? You are overwriting the first value which is a resizable image.

Comment: Are you setting a background for the segmenedControll?

Comment: They are set twice ... for ios7 (first in if, because only ios7 responds to that selector) and then for ios6.

Comment: yes I am setting a background for the segmentedControll

Comment: I am having exact same issue, i have a feeling it's a bug or it's how it is in iOS 7. I tried every option i could think of reading the docs. I tried changing the content offset to negative value which moves things so that means by default there's padding which cannot be changed