# Incorrect tint for selected segment of UISegmentedControl on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a UISegmentedControl in a UIToolbar with custom background/divider images. Through iOS 6 this displayed correctly, but as of iOS 7 the selected segment is showing the foreground image for that segment as a cutout (revealing the toolbar underneath) rather than the white the other segments are showing as.

[image: Incorrect tint color on iOS 7]

Any ideas on if there's just something I'm missing to make it behave as expected?

Before anyone says it, I am not going to use the default iOS 7 UISegmentedControl appearance since I find it hideous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out shortly after posting.

`UISegmentedControl` interprets its images as being in rendering mode `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate` unless otherwise specified.

I had to use - `[UIImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]` on each segment's image for `iOS 7` to achieve the previous behavior.

Comment: can you help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850081/ios7-images-inuisegmentedcontrol-not-scaling

Answer (score 2):

Use this code to set image on Segment Control in iOS 7 with xCode 5

```
if ([UIImage instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(imageWithRenderingMode:)]) {

    [segmentControl setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] forSegmentAtIndex:0];

}
else {
    [segmentControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
}
```