# UISegmentedControl in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a project with two segmented controls. They both worked up to iOS7.0. Now one does not. I've read of issues with tintColor, but I think this is something different.

Both controls use UIImages as segments. On one, the images all show correctly. On the other, I get all *blue* images.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Here's the code of the faulty segment:

```
UISegmentedControl *colorControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
    [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"],
    [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple.png"],
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black.png"], nil]];



    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + kLeftMargin, rect.size.height - kPaletteHeight - kTopMargin, rect.size.width - (kLeftMargin + kRightMargin), kPaletteHeight );
    colorControl.frame = frame;

    // Add DoubleTap Color capability

    gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showMoreColors:)];
    [gesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

    [colorControl addGestureRecognizer:gesture];

    // When the user chooses a color, the method changeColor: is called.
    [colorControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Make sure the color of the color complements the black background
    //colorControl.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Add the control to the window
    [self.view addSubview:colorControl];
```

While the images are all blue, the segments work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730667/uisegmentedcontrol-setimage-bug-in-ios7?rq=1), I formulated the following fix:

```
-(void) buildColorBar {
    //NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    UIImage *whiteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"White.png"];
    UIImage *blackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Black.png"];
    UIImage *purpleImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purple.png"];
    UIImage *redImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"];
    UIImage *blueImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue.png"];
    UIImage *greenImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
    UIImage *yellowImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow.png"];

    NSArray *colorArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                    [whiteImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal],
                    [redImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ],
                    [yellowImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ],
                    [greenImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ],
                    [blueImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ],
                    [purpleImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ],
                    [blackImage imageWithRenderingMode: UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ], nil ];


    UISegmentedControl *colorControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:colorArray];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x + kLeftMargin, rect.size.height - kPaletteHeight - kTopMargin, rect.size.width - (kLeftMargin + kRightMargin), kPaletteHeight );
    colorControl.frame = frame;
```

I hope it helps someone else.